# How to display a list containing certain elements at certain indexes?

Tags: python, indexing

I've been trying to get Python 2.7 to display anything from a list (or string, tuple, etc.) if said list contains certain elements in certain positions.

Say I know that for the list `l`, `l[1]` should be `3`, `l[2]` should be `1`, and `l[5]` should be `5`. I want to print `l` iff these conditions hold, but I'm stuck at writing the `contains_at` function.

```
indexes = (1, 2, 5)
elements = (7, 1, 8)

l1 = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1]
l2 = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5]


def print_if_contains_at(l, idxs, elts):
    # some function that returns True if I should print the list
    if contains_at(l, idxs, elts):
        print(l)

# prints the entire list l1
print_if_contains_at(l1, indexes, elements)


# prints nothing, since l2 doesn't contain the correct pattern of elements
print_if_contains_at(l2, indexes, elements)
```

Comment: Are you trying to apply a fixed mask to a given input? Are you looking for a specific pattern? Your clarification edit still doesn't look like legal python. Why is the user typing code into the input? It's not clear what is code and what is input/output. Although this will probably end up being a very simple regex.

Comment: @KennyOstrom The attempt was to show that I don't know of any method to force python to print on screen the entire string with a certain set of elements at a certain index.

Comment: see my first comment, please. Just one concrete example? I already implemented this one and it wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: @KennyOstrom This is the closest I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working `contains_at`. Read through tutorials on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [zip](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/) to understand what it's doing.

```python
indexes = (1, 2, 5)
elements = (7, 1, 8)

l1 = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1]
l2 = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5]


def contains_at(l, idxs, elts):
    return all(l[idx] == elt for idx, elt in zip(idxs, elts))


def print_if_contains_at(l, idxs, elts):
    if contains_at(l, idxs, elts):
        print(l)


print_if_contains_at(l1, indexes, elements)
print_if_contains_at(l2, indexes, elements)

# prints only [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNCsMgEIX3nmKWCm6SNv2DnCSEEBqlwtQEtZD28nY0WXSRklkM@t43D53pHR6jLWM0dlCz8lADLySUEirBFKqnsiGLZwmkXwRjWNC9IWKVMk29aBmWyTpk/Zh7JeGagROdW8bYoDRMztjQGd3dRxt6Y33XB44SzDB7CQqDFzcGVEbDHpIq53EUS/rehFPh5Sz0iBwbcluo6@SDHl2iMwzGwsdM/Gea4rcfTt9ct5fIZWV/4XILjvEL)

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I can come up with is the most rigid and non-flexible solution that does the same job.  This would work for a small amount of lists, however it would be exhaustive to write myriad steps.

```
a = input('Enter the string')

b,c,d = input('Enter the the three index elements you are looking for')

    if a in b[0:3]:

                  print(string)
```